# Shortening Knuth's algorithm M (mixed-radix numbers) in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

This is the C++ code of my implementation of Knuth's algorithm M that produces mixed-radix numbers:

```
#include "visit.h"

void algorithmM(vector<int>& m)
{
  m.insert(m.begin(),2);
  const int n=m.size();
  vector<int> a(n,0);
  M2:
  visit(false,a);
  int j=n-1;
  M4:
  if (a[j]==m[j]-1) {a[j]=0;--j;goto M4;}
  if (j==0) return;
  else {a[j]++;goto M2;}
  }
int main()
{
  vector<int> m;
  int i;
  while(std::cin>>i)
  {if(i<0) continue;
   m.push_back(i);
  }
algorithmM(m);
return 0;
}
```

This is the code of "visit.h":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

template<class T> void visit(bool first,vector<T>& l)
{
 size_t dt=first?0:1;
 for(typename vector<T>::iterator i=l.begin()+dt;i!=l.end();++i)
cout<<*i;
 cout<<'\n';
}
```

The C++ code is very close to the Knuth's pseudocode. And now this is an imperative Haskell implementation using mutable arrays:

```
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.IORef

data CountList = CountList {intlist::[Int],count::Int}
lenarr arr = do
         b<-getBounds arr
         return (snd b)

takeInput :: State (String,Int) [Int]
takeInput = do
        (s,count)<-get
        let g=reads s
        if g==[] then return []
        else do
            put (snd(head g),count+1)
            l<-takeInput
            return $ (fst(head g)):l
takeInput2 :: String->CountList
takeInput2 s = let (l,ss)=runState (takeInput) (s,0)
        in CountList l (snd ss)

fillArray :: CountList->IO((IOArray Int Int),(IOArray Int Int))
fillArray l = do
        arr<-newArray (0,(count l)) 0
        x<-nowfill 1 (intlist l) arr
        y<-newArray (0,(count l)) 0
        writeArray x 0 2
        return (x,y)

 where nowfill i l arr = do
             if l==[] then return arr
             else do
                writeArray arr i (head l)
                nowfill (i+1) (tail l) arr
visit ::(IOArray Int Int)->Int->IO ()
visit x i = do
          c<-lenarr x
          if i>c then putStrLn ""
          else do
                a<-readArray x i
                putStr (show a)
                visit x (i+1)

maj :: (IOArray Int Int)->(IOArray Int Int)->Int->IO((IOArray Int Int),Int)
maj m a j = do
        valaj <- readArray a j
        valmj <- readArray m j
        if valaj==valmj-1 then
                  do
                      writeArray a j 0
                      maj m a (j-1)
        else
            return (a,j)
m5 :: (IOArray Int Int)->Int->IO((IOArray Int Int),Int)
m5 a j = if j==0 then
         return (a,j)
     else do
         valaj<-readArray a j
         writeArray a j (valaj+1)
         return (a,j)
algorithmM0 m a = do
    visit a 1
    n<-lenarr m
    (a',j)<-maj m a n
    (a'',j')<-m5 a' j
    if j'==0 then
          return ()
    else
        algorithmM0 m a''
algorithmM = do
    l<-getLine
    let mycountlist = takeInput2 l
    (m,a)<-fillArray mycountlist
    algorithmM0 m a
main :: IO ()
main = algorithmM
```

I also have and a more functional approach using lists in Haskell which is smaller but I don't want to enlarge the post.

Can you please give me some advice on how to shrink the Haskell code?

I think that the main reason of using a high-level language like Haskell is to write less code but I don't think this happens here so I suppose that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'd say the main reason to write in Haskell is to write well expressed code. If you insist on writing in an imperative idiom, and you want it to look the same, you can't expect it to be significantly shorter, just have a bit less syntax. Out of interest, what's wrong with your lists version? Is it too slow?

Comment: I second that you seem very attached to writing this algorithm imperatively, and I find that strange.

Comment: Knuth himself says "Algorithm M is simple and straightforward, but we shouldn't forget that nested loops are even simpler, when n is fairly small and constant." In Haskell, we can remove the "small and constant" restriction and allow arbitrary lists of multiple radixes, with `alg = mapM (\n -> [0..n-1])` as in user5402's and Daniel Wagner's answers. You go against Knuth's advice and stick with a less simple version, refuse a 21-character functional version that fixes the inflexibility of the imperative version then complain that your code is too long? That's honestly not Haskell's fault.

Comment: You said "I think that the main reason of using a high-level language like Haskell is to write less code but I don't think this happens here so I suppose that I am doing something wrong." The "something wrong" is rejecting the functional idiom and its beautifully terse `mapM (\n -> [0..n-1])` solution to your problem. Years ago a friend proudly explained a C program he wrote for managing a bunch of data. I wrote some Haskell, literally on the back of an envelope to do the same. _"Is that it?"_ "Yes. Why, is your code roughly ten times as long?" _"Yes."_ I had avoided the imperative idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functional approach is very succinct:

```
algom = sequence . map (\n -> [0..n-1])

algom [2,3,4]
  -- [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,1,4],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],[1,3,4],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,1,4],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,2,4],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],[2,3,4]]
```

Even if you implement a shorter version of Algorithm M it will still be in the IO monad, and so any code that uses it will also have to be in the IO monad (or the ST monad if you use ST arrays.)

Unless there is a pressing reason to use a mutable array, I would just stick with the functional version.

In any case, here is a mutable array version of Algorithm M:

```
import Data.Array.MArray (getBounds,writeArray,readArray,newArray,getElems)
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad.Loops (untilM_)


next :: IOArray Int Int -> IOArray Int Int -> IO Bool
next rarr arr =                              -- radix array, digit array
  do (first,last) <- getBounds arr
     let go k | k < first = return True      -- end reached
         go k = do d <- readArray arr k
                   r <- readArray rarr k
                   let newd = d+1
                   if newd >= r
                     then do writeArray arr k 0
                             go (k-1)
                     else do writeArray arr k newd
                             return False    -- more to come
     go last

showArray :: IOArray Int Int -> IO ()
showArray arr = do
  nums <- getElems arr
  putStrLn $ show nums


(-->) = flip fmap

main = do nums <- getContents --> words --> map read --> takeWhile (>= 0)
          let n = length nums
          rarr <- newListArray (1,n) nums
          arr <- newArray (1,n)  0
          untilM_ (showArray arr) (next rarr arr)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it does not satisfy me. 1) It does not reproduce the mixed-radix algorithm. It uses only one radix (both the functional and the imperative) 2) It does not request input from the user 3) The imperative version is not less than the C++ version.

Comment: @Dragno User input is a trivial change: `let algo = sequence . map (\n -> [0..n-1]) in fmap (algo.map read.words) getLine` You can replace `getLine` with `(putStrLn "Enter the radixes you want to use, separated by spaces">>getLine)` if you're feeling particularly user friendly.

Answer (score 5):

The pure part of algorithm M is quite short indeed:

```
algorithmM = mapM (\n -> [0..n-1])
```

For example, here's a run in ghci:

```
> algorithmM [2,3]
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]
```

It's also quite easy to put an input/output loop around it. For example, we could add

```
main = readLn >>= mapM_ print . algorithmM
```

Compile and run a program containing these two (!) lines, and you will see something like this:

```
% ./test
[2,3]
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
```